# Commercial Text Summarization Tools

Tags: text-mining

I'm looking for commercial text summarization tools (APIs, Libraries,...) which are able to perform any of the following tasks:

1. Extractive Multi-Document Summarization (Generic or query-based)
2. Extractive Single-Document Summarization (Generic or query-based)
3. Generative Single-Document Summarization (Generic or query-based)
4. Generative Multi-Document Summarization (Generic or query-based)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of open source options I know of -

LibOTS - http://libots.sourceforge.net/

DocSum - http://docsum.sourceforge.net/docsum/web/about.php

A couple of commercial solutions -

Intellix Summarizer Pro - http://summarizer.intellexer.com/order_summarizer_pro.php

Copernic Summarizer - http://www.copernic.com/en/products/summarizer/

And this one is a web service -

TextTeaser - http://www.textteaser.com/

I'm sure there are plenty of others out there.  I have used Copernic a good deal and it's pretty good, but I was hoping it could be automated easily, which it can't - at least it couldn't when I used it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already know these tools. Unfortunatly none of them are neither able to summarize a collection of documents nor perform query-based summarization